# Android crash with minifyEnabled and AWS call

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, proguard, minify

Using variety of aws-android-sdk's (version 2.22.0) (including DynamoDB).

With `minifyEnabled = true`, Android app crashes in DynamoDB call.  App does not crash if I disable that flag.

Here are the proguard-rules I'm using:

In build.gradle (app):

```
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

And in the proguard-rules.pro I have the following:

```
# Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepnames class com.amazon.**

# Enums are not obfuscated correctly in combination with Gson
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

# Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler

# The following are referenced but aren't required to run
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**

# Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

# The SDK has several references of Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**
```

Here's the pertinent call stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
    Process: com.icefield.eventtruly, PID: 20298
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.processKeyConditions(:2711)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.createQueryRequestFromExpression(:2671)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(:2438)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(:2399)
        at c.f.a.g.d$b.run(:339)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Setting `minifyEnabled = false` results in everything working hunky-dory.

Any ideas on what else I might add to proguard rules?

Comment: were you able to make it work with minifyEnabled = true?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following ProGuard rules.

```
-keep class com.amazon.** { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-keep class com.amplifyframework.** { *; }
```

I suspect that you'll find a
`ClassNotFoundException` or and/or `NoClassDefFoundError` elsewhere in your logs, which will be more helpful to fine-tune the rules.

The particular error you're seeing [arises when there are no key `Condition`s](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/b627102414c65b5dcfb26ae7543450bf0f0b7c3a/aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/DynamoDBMapper.java#L2712) included in the request being sent to DyanmoDB.